# Confusion with the naming of 'LocalDateTime' in NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm confused with the naming of `LocalDateTime` in NodaTime.
Reading the documentation, it appears that it says:

> A LocalDateTime value does not represent an instant on the global time line, because it has no associated time zone

Therefore, I would interpret this as:

> "If I create a `LocalDateTime` in daylight savings, it doesn't matter, because this LocalDateTime has no knowledge of TimeZone and therefore no known offset from UTC."

Therefore, if I want to convert that `LocalDateTime` to UTC, I must do this:

```
// We can't convert directly to UTC because it doesn't know its own offset from UTC.
var dt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDt, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

// We specify the timezone as Melbourne Time, 
// because we know this time refers to Melbourne time. 
// This will attach a known offset and create a ZonedDateTime.
// Remember that if the system time variable (dt) is in daylight savings, it doesn't
// matter, because LocalDateTime does not contain such information.
// Therefore 8:00 PM in Daylight Savings and 8:00 PM outside of daylight savings
// are both 8:00 PM when we created the ZonedDateTime as below.
var melbCreatedTime = createdTime.InZoneLeniently(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Melbourne"]);

// Now we can get to UTC, because we have a ZonedDateTime and therefore
// have a known offset from UTC:
sharedB.CreatedUTC = melbCreatedTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
```

Is this correct? DateTime logic is by far my weakest area, and I just want to make sure I understand what's happening here.

Without the comments:

```
var dateCreatedLocal = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(result.DateCreated.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
var dateCreatedUtc = dateCreatedLocal.InZoneLeniently(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Melbourne"]).ToDateTimeUtc();
sharedB.CreatedUTC = dateCreatedUtc;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just run it with test data and you will see.

Comment: @madreflection Does that mean my comprehension of it is correct?

Comment: From what I can tell, yeah, the logic appears to be what you want. Optional Option is right, though. You should run it through a battery of tests and verify it. That's the only way to really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of a "`LocalDateTime` in daylight savings". It's *just* a date and time, with no reference to any time zone that might or might not be observing DST.

However, if your aim is just to go from a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified` to a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Utc` using a particular time zone, I'd *normally* suggest using `TimeZoneInfo` - unless you specifically need IANA time zone ID support.

In general, I'd suggest using the Noda Time types everywhere - or if you're going to use the BCL types everywhere, don't use Noda Time at all. There are some cases where it makes sense to use Noda Time just for an isolated piece of code, and if you really *need* to do that here, then I believe your code should be fine - but be aware of the implications of `InZoneLeniently` when it comes to ambiguous or skipped local times around daylight saving changes (or other offset changes).

Comment: Thank you, the reason I was using NodaTime for this particular case is because our frontend and backend both use IANA timezones, and from what I understand, the BCL types don't support it. However, our backend heavily uses BCL types, so I need to convert to and from NodaTime just so I can use the IANA timezones, as it isn't practical to convert all instances of the BCL types.